# Web services development vs Web services integration | iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services

This question is about, estimation of one iPhone application development, the estimation which I have received has 32 hours for web services development and 40 hours for web services integration. I'm layman and does not have in depth technical knowledge.. However, I do understand that, web services integration takes less efforts than web services development. Can anyone help me to understand if I'm right or wrong ? Your answer will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically web service integration/consumption take less time if and only if you have sound knowledge on it. In web service integration you have to just call web service and take some from from it. Remaining part of, treatment on data is depending on your functionality and skills.
If you call data from server and it store it local database and again take data from local database after showing it on your UI then it will take time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. The web service integration can be made much easy with the help of frameworks such as `AFNetworking` or by using default iOS framework for network communication. You just need to call the web service api and parse the data accordingly. But all the logic and processing of data to be done in web service implementation can cost a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Estimation of web service integration completely depends on what has been included in ‘integration’. If integration is simply taking the response and converting it in desired data structure, then it should take less than web service development. On the other hand if integration includes converting the response into desired data structure and developing functionalities using the data then it may take more than the development time.